# Ввод числовых данных котлин

Tags: kotlin, input

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
     println("Введи данные")
     val (a, b, c) Float = readLine()
     println("Дискриминант:")
     var d : Float = b*b - 4*a*c
     println(d)
    }
```

Я догадываюсь, что readline работает только для стринг, но каким образом вводить числовые данные в котлине?

Answer (score 1):

```
fun main(args:Array<String>){
println("Введи данные")
var a :Float = readLine()!!.toFloat()  
var b :Float = readLine()!!.toFloat()  
var c :Float = readLine()!!.toFloat()  
println("Дискриминант:")
var d : Float = b*b - 4*a*c
println(d)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)
val a = scan.nextInt() // для целых
val b = scan.nextFloat() // для вещественных
```